# How to define language of the page to be scraped

Tags: web-scraping

I wanted to save Finnish version of the site: [https://lovelace.oulu.fi/tietokonejärjestelmät/tietokonejärjestelmät/](https://lovelace.oulu.fi/tietokonej%C3%A4rjestelm%C3%A4t/tietokonej%C3%A4rjestelm%C3%A4t/) to Wayback machine. But it saved the [English version](https://web.archive.org/web/20230506093706/https://lovelace.oulu.fi/tietokonej%C3%A4rjestelm%C3%A4t/tietokonej%C3%A4rjestelm%C3%A4t/konekieli/).

On my browser the page is viewed in Finnish, I don't know what to do when scraping to set preferred language to Finnish.

The same happened when I tried using other scraping service/software such as [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/)

I tried appending ?lang=fi or django_language=fi to the url but that didn't work.

I would like the scraper to download the Finnish version of the page and or site.

In the upper right corner of the page is a language selection dropdown list where you can select Suomi(fi) or English(en).

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know if this can be done in Wayback machine, but with [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) you can specify the preferred languages with the "-%l" flag.

Usage example: `-%l "fr, en, jp, *"`

Documentation here:
http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html